# What is the best way to configure my VM from within Azure vnet post-deployment?

Tags: azure

I'm working on a project where I'm deploying a VM to a private vnet (10.0.0.0/24) in Azure. The VM hosts a web API, but for **reasons** I can't log into it via ssh or change any of the code that runs on the VM. Once the VM deployment is complete, I need to do some automated post-deploy tasks such as patching the VM and changing default login credentials which I can do via the API. Once the post-deploy tasks are complete, the API running on the VM will be made public via an App Gateway.

What's the best way to perform these post-deployment tasks? I was looking at using an Azure Function. It wasn't clear to me whether there is a way to connect to the VM API from an Azure Function. Is there a better/standard way of doing something like this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have more options, such as possibility of setting up email alerts and complex integration, you can consider [Azure Logic Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview). It's also [possible to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56288606/best-approach-to-call-web-api-from-azure-function) it using an Azure Function.

Just in case the situation changes and you do get access to the machine or have a say on how it's deployed, here are some other options. These might less likely apply in your case, but I'm hoping it turns out to be relevant to you or others.

You can get all of this in an Azure Custom Script Extension, [in PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows) if you're using Windows and or [in Bash](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux) if you're using Linux.

[Azure Automation State Configuration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-dsc-overview) is another way to go about it, using Desired State Configuration for [Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dsc/getting-started/lnxgettingstarted?view=powershell-7.1) or [Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dsc/overview/overview?view=powershell-7.1).